# What families often have Merchant Patrons?

Tags: l5r, l5r-4e

I know that the Ide, Daidoji, Yoritomo and obviously the Yasuki is mention in the source material as often having members whom are Merchant Patrons.

There is also a reference that the Lion sees itself as above things like commerce and have very few merchant patrons among their number.

But what of the other clans? What families among the other clans (and the Lion for that matter) is normally the one to deal with the matter of commerce and trade and thus is the most common one to include merchant patrons among their numbers?
(I mean, both the Dragon and the Phoenix have trade stations outside the Empire, so there must be some after all.)

Answer (score 3):

Any Samurai is capable of being a Merchant Patron. However, each clan has a family that is slightly more likely to do said patroning than others.

Crab - Yasuki are the courtiers. Their school is also known for being merchants.

Crane - Daidoji is the family that does the "dirty work" for the rest of the clan, and thus are typically the merchant patrons.

Dragon - Kitsuki or Mirumoto. They are the two more worldly of the families, and either is likely to put the effort in.

Lion - The Ikoma have a tendency to do what's needed on behalf of the clan. They won't advertise their efforts quite as loudly as, say, the Yoritomo or Yasuki, but you can be sure that the Lion clan supports their merchants as heavily as any other clan.

Mantis - Yoritomo. They rule the sea trade. Sometimes, they don't even bother with the Patron part of the title.

Phoenix - Shiba. Phoenix are, much like the Lion, unlikely to advertise their efforts, but their more worldly family is sure to have merchant patrons to ensure their clan doesn't get screwed in the markets.

Scorpion - Shosuro (and, more rarely, Bayushi). They do what has to be done. Often times, the merchants they support produce less reputable goods, but honestly, they thought that opium was intended for medicinal use!

Unicorn - Ide. They have an alternate path called the Ide Trader.

Spider - nobody cares to openly trade with these murderous fiends.

Minor Clans - each clan handles their own trade, but the Kasuga are particularly skilled at it.